# Firestore Pagination: How do I load the next set of data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

here is my code to load the first 100 documents in the collection:

```
db.collection("books").where("ItemType", "==", "Book").limit(100)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot=>{
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc=>{
                    console.log(doc.data())
                    let data = doc.data();
                    let row  = `<tr>
                                    <td>${data.Title}</td>
                                   
                            </tr>`;
                    let table = document.getElementById('myTable')
                    table.innerHTML += row
                })
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
            });
```

How do I keep on loading the next 100 documents upon a press of a button?

```
function LoadMore(){
    //Load 100 more documents
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `startAt(doc)` or `startAfter(doc)`.
Just provide field values or DocumentSnapshot of doc from your last query.

In your case it would be:

```
db.collection("books").where("ItemType", "==", "Book")
.startAfter(lastDocFromFirstQuery).limit(100).get();
```

**Answer for your edited question**

```
// define this somewhere globally
let lastDoc;

// use just this function
function queryBooks() {
  let query;

  // if lastDoc is already defined then use it as a reference point for firestore
  if (lastDoc != null) {
    query = fsDb.collection("books").where("ItemType", "==", "Book").startAfter(lastDoc);
  } else {
    query = fsDb.collection("books").where("ItemType", "==", "Book");
  }

  query.limit(100).get().then(querySnapshot=>{

        lastDoc = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];

        querySnapshot.forEach(doc=>{
          console.log(doc.data())
          let data = doc.data();
          let row  = `<tr>
                                <td>${data.Title}</td>
                               
                        </tr>`;
          let table = document.getElementById('myTable')
          table.innerHTML += row
        })
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
      });
}
```

Comment: Could you please show me how I can provide the DocumentSnapshot of the document of the last query, thanks

Comment: `let lastDocSnapshot = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];` you can type 99 too but its better to do it this way since you dont know if you will read 100 docs, you could read just 50. So with this you will retrieve the last doc, then you should store it and when user requests next docs, use it.

Comment: Hi I have updated the content of my question

Comment: I’ve edited my answe too, does it answer the question?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I tried using the same code, and it displays the same 100 documents as before

Comment: Hmm it’s hard when i dont see the whole code, are you sure there isn’t issue somewhere else? The main point is to store that last document from last query and preserve it until next query so you have a reference point for firestore. Are you sure you are doing that right? Try to include some console.log() in if else statement part of the code, to see whats happening and which query is being initialized, and also print lastDoc if it isnt null after querying.

Comment: Hi, im afraid the code in your answer is the whole code